# need help to create Webservice with HTTPS

Tags: java, security, ssl, https

I have written my webservice with https. but as per requirement I should provide authentication. so thought of going with SSL (HTTPs). Could anyone help me with steps like moving HTTP to HTTPs and SSL certification part with step by step.

i did by adding below in service and axis xml files:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/root/my_workspace/server.keystore"              keystorePass="changeit"/>

<transportReceiver name="http" class= "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">  
   <parameter name="port">8080</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
<transportReceiver name="https" class= "org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServletListener">  
   <parameter name="port">8443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

but I don't want to access through HTTP. How can I restrict?

Also I created the WDSL request via eclipse, the value tag starts with "`q0`" and response has return tag as well. so how can avoid and go with custom req/response?

Comment: please ask this question on => http://security.stackexchange.com/ ...u'll get better response there as SO is for codes and bugs!!

Answer (score 1):

Making your Http connection over SSL i.e. Https , you need to enable SSL in your application server by providing a certificate (either self-signed or CA provided). It is not related to the application code.Please refer the documentation of your application server to enable SSL.For example, this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html) provides information about how to configure SSL in tomcat 7

Comment: i did by adding below in service and axis xml files.
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
    keystoreFile="/root/my_workspace/server.keystore"              keystorePass="changeit"/>

Comment: Yes i accpet your answer and thanks alot.
Can u please give client code how to access the hhtps page?

Comment: ok, I don't have any ready made code. but [this](http://axis.apache.org/axis/java/user-guide.html#Consuming_Web_Services_with_Axis) will help

Comment: This sample code to access http. but i wants to access https. could any provide.

Comment: I have another issue also which i mentioned in my question block in last.

Comment: Please ask that as a different question.so, everyone can view it as opened and answer